# How do you retrieve the data from MySQL using sub or join queries?

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have a table named 'doctor_tbl' with following columns:

```
doctor_id   pid   owner_name         companyname    fleet_group   vehicle_number    driver_name   
59          NULL  PTS Owner            PTS        3          NULL              NULL
60          NULL  ABT Mahalingam       ABT        3          NULL              NULL
61          NULL  Ind Jai        Indi Jai         2          TN55-7854           Ind Jai
62          61     NULL            NULL           3          TN4564564       Ind Jai's Driver
63          59     NULL            NULL           3         TT-65-DD6589    PTS Driver
64          NULL   FCmp O'name    Test Company        3         NULL
65          64     NULL            NULL           3         455353          FCmp Test Driver
67          64     NULL           NULL        3           XZE4544              Joe
68          59     NULL           NULL        3         433534534         Test F Driver 2
70          64     NULL           NULL        3         SDF3433            Samson
```

From value 59,60,64 are companies and 63,65,66,67,68,70 are drivers of this companies and 61 is an individual driver (who has only few cars and he is also an driver to one of his car) and he has another driver 62.
Now i want to display the driver list from 62 to 70 including individual drive. While doing joins i getting following values but not getting the company name of the individual driver - Indi Jai when i do code into my php - codeigniter.

```html
doctor_id pid driver_name vehicle_type vehicle_number companyname fleet_group companyname  
61          NULL  Ind Jai  Hitech Open  TN55-7854  Indi Jai     2            NULL
62          61  Ind Jai Driver  Hitech Open  464564564  NULL             3        Indi Jai
63          59  PTS Driver  Hitech Open  TT-65-DD6589  NULL             3             PTS
65          64  FCmp Test DriverHitech Closed  455353        NULL             3      Test First Company
67          64  joe             Hitech Open  XZE4544          NULL             3      Test First Company
68          59  Test F Driver 2 Hitech Open  433534534  NULL             3              PTS
70          64  samson          Hitech Closed  SDF3433        NULL             3     Test First Company
```

Here my query and can any one tell where i missed ....

```
select dtbl.doctor_id, dtbl.pid,dtbl.picture, dtbl.driver_name, dtbl.vehicle_type,
    dtbl.vehicle_number,dtbl.companyname,dtbl.fleet_group,dtblb.companyname 
from doctor_tbl as dtbl 
left join doctor_tbl as dtblb ON dtblb.doctor_id=dtbl.pid 
where dtbl.driver_name !=""
```

Result which i receiving

[image: enter image description here - https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Mc7U.png]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `COALESCE()` to combine `dtbl.companyname` and `dtblb.companyname` in a single column, showing the firstone that is not null.

```
select dtbl.doctor_id, dtbl.pid,dtbl.picture, dtbl.driver_name, dtbl.vehicle_type,
    dtbl.vehicle_number, dtbl.fleet_group,
    COALESCE(dtblb.companyname, dtbl.companyname) AS companyname
from doctor_tbl as dtbl 
left join doctor_tbl as dtblb ON dtblb.doctor_id=dtbl.pid 
where dtbl.driver_name !=""
```